# NVD3 / D3 values out of chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have the following issue with my chart :

[image]

As you see it gets the max values out of the chart.

My code is :

```
d3.json('/url here', function(data) {
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
          .x(function(d) { return d.date  })
          .y(function(d) { return d.total })
          .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
                .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
                .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis;
    chart.xAxis
        .showMaxMin(false)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %d %Y')(new Date(d)); });

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .style('height', '400px')
        .call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cat_button");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].id = type;
        }
    return chart;
  });
```

Can you point me to a fix?
Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a problem with the data. Can you add an example of what you are using?

Comment: Have you tried `chart.yAxis.showMaxMin(true)`?

Comment: showMaxMin(true) doesn't seem to work ...